# Django development add-ons

Tags: python, django

I have come across various [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) development add ons, particularly,

- [django-extensions](http://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/tree/master)
- [django-annoying](http://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/)
- [django-debug-toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar/tree/master)
- [django-tools](http://code.google.com/p/greatlemers-django-tools/)

I haven't exactly used all of these.

I think it is hard to beat the simplicity and power obtained by the combination of Django's pretty error pages combined with iPythonEmbed shell.

Which of these or other tools do you use for development, what exact features do you benefit out of it?

Self-written commands and scripts are welcome too.

Answer (score 3):

I for one love [django-annoying](http://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/)'s `render_to` method.

```
@render_to('template.html')
def foo(request):
    bar = Bar.objects.all() 
    return {'bar': bar}

# equivalent to
def foo(request):
    bar = Bar.objects.all() 
    return render_to_response('template.html',
                              {'bar': bar},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I've not used any of the others yet, though I've been looking at django-debug-toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

I use [django-extensions](http://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/tree/master) in every project. There's a lot of stuff in there I never use, but it's worth it for the management commands [shell_plus](http://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/ebf37ffb52e4d41c3c678c12dfb1138abdff1ea9/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py) and [runserver_plus](http://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/ebf37ffb52e4d41c3c678c12dfb1138abdff1ea9/django_extensions/management/commands/runserver_plus.py) alone.

Shell_plus just autoloads all your models: a major timesaver (**EDIT**: forgot something equally important: it also makes use of [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/) if installed, for tab completion and other conveniences).  Runserver_plus (requires Werkzeug) gives you an interactive 500 error debug page.  You can jump into an AJAX console at any point in the traceback - brilliant.

The [print_user_for_session](http://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/ebf37ffb52e4d41c3c678c12dfb1138abdff1ea9/django_extensions/management/commands/print_user_for_session.py) command is also handy if you get an error email off a live site and want to contact the user who experienced the error.

**update**: Django's built-in management shell also now uses IPython if available. And it's relatively easy to create an IPython user profile to auto-import models and anything else you want auto-imported. I no longer use django-extensions.

Comment: Auto-loading all your models sounds great!  I wrote a script for that a while back and haven't used the shell command since.  (Also, auto-loading django.contrib.auth.models.User is a big deal, since it's so long to type in a shell.)

Answer (score 1):

I have found [django-logging](http://code.google.com/p/django-logging/wiki/Overview) to be a big help during development

Answer (score 1):

```
from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed
ipshell = IPShellEmbed()

ipshell() # This call anywhere in your program will start IPython.
```

This way, when you are at a view, you can get into the command line there and explore. All required models will be imported anyway and are an easy replacement for `shell_plus`. To me, it even replaces the `runserver_plus` of `django-command-extensions`.

(Because I found what I use often, is not a common prevalent idea, I answered it myself.)

Answer (score 1):

Try [djangodevtools](http://os4d.org/djangodevtools), including the commands `Alias`, `Coverage`, `itest`, `selenium`, etc. Some extra commands are very cool!

Answer (score 0):

The single most useful Django development addon we use is  [django-evolution](http://code.google.com/p/django-evolution/).  It is a schema update solution that takes a lot of the manual work out of changes in existing models. It has saved me countless hours of work.